# Catching ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

How can I catch ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS with .htaccess or even in PHP and redirect to 404 page?

Print: http://prntscr.com/j0xh1m

It's possible? Thanks anyway

Comment: What have you tried before coming to SO?

Comment: I've tried using ErrorDocument in htacess and header location with PHP

Comment: Can we see the code you used? :)

Comment: I just used a simple code to check if the GET parameter exists, if not, the page load the ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS error, so I tried verifying it like _if (!isset($_GET['type'])) { header("location: 404.php"); }_ ... But still not working, I'm not able to catch this error

Comment: Also, _ErrorDocument 404 404.php_ doesn't works too

Comment: Try var_dumping $_GET to see what's actually being passed, may be different to what you're expecting

Comment: Check the server access log and see what's getting redirected

Comment: I know it's possible to fix this. But do not you think this is not efficient? I believe that exists something more powerful than this

Comment: Like a global way to detect without check all parameters manually

Answer (score 0):

`ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS` is a browser error, you cannot catch it at server level. You may only try to detect whether the user has fallen into a redirect loop and display your error page before browser will block redirections.

But correct solution is fixing your app and avoid redirection loops in the first place.

Comment: How can I detect if user has fallen into a redirect loop?

Comment: I don't know any reliable way. You may try to track every response for every session and detect consecutive redirections to the same page for the same session, but it is neither simple nor reliable. That's why I suggest fixing this error in your app - it should be simpler than creating nice error page for it.